# Unable to hide page properties tab for Granite Dialog(Touch UI) in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

I have a requirement to hide the cloud services and permissions tab in the page properties for a particular set of user group. I also have two of my custom tabs in the page properties.

When I create a rep:policy node and add the deny permission for that particular group my custom tabs are hidden but the OOTB tabs like Cloud Services , Permissions are not hidden. Please note I have overridden the cq:dialog from libs to apps.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Ashish

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<cloudservices jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideResource="true"/>
<permissions jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:hideResource="true" />
```

Source :- http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__nkzm-i_have_a_requirement.html

~kautuk